# Android - Nuller Pointer exception at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, nullpointerexception, listadapter

I have a problem when i try put into a list view an array adapter. 
The logcat is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2186)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15683)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4936)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15683)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4936)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15683)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4936)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15683)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4936)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15683)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4936)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
```

My Java Class  in which i have my list view is:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    dialog = new Dialog(Settings.this);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.altro);
    causali = prendiCausali();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Settings.this,R.layout.row_style, new ArrayList<String>());

    LinkedList<String> caus = new LinkedList<String>(); 

    caus.addAll(Arrays.asList(causali));

    for (int i=0;i<caus.size(); i++) {
        adapter.add(caus.get(i));
    }

    ListView lwcausali = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listViewDemo);

    lwcausali.setAdapter(adapter);

    dialog.setTitle("Cancella");
    dialog.show();
}
```

And the function `prendiCausali()` is:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory strumentiDati = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
Document doc = null;
DocumentBuilder manipoloDati = null;
try {
    manipoloDati = strumentiDati.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = manipoloDati.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Ebadge/Causali/causali.xml"));
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
NodeList nodi = doc.getElementsByTagName("causale");
for (int i = 0; i < nodi.getLength(); i++) {
    Node nodoItem = nodi.item(i);
    if (nodoItem.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element elemento = (Element) nodoItem;

        causali[i] = (elemento.getElementsByTagName("nome").item(0).getTextContent());
        Log.d("c1", causali[i]);
    }
}
return causali;
```

It's one week that I try to fix this problem!
Sorry for my english!
I hope in an answer
Thanks

Comment: please post your adapter code

Comment: You're trying to show a list in a dialog right?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not using a spinner?

Comment: @Rashmi I don't think he is using a custom adapter. Can you post your row_style.xml?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    

</TextView>

Comment: @ AndyFaizan  yes! i try to show a textview, a button and a listview in a dialog

Answer (score 0):

You are calling for layout property before dialog's on create call, which is a callback triggered on .show(), give a little order and I guess it will work

```
dialog = new Dialog(Settings.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.altro);
dialog.setTitle("Cancella");
dialog.show(); // move it to here

causali = prendiCausali();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Settings.this,R.layout.row_style, new ArrayList<String>());

LinkedList<String> caus = new LinkedList<String>(); 
caus.addAll(Arrays.asList(causali));

for (int i=0;i<caus.size(); i++) {
    adapter.add(caus.get(i));
}
ListView lwcausali = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listViewDemo);
lwcausali.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like one of your items is null, so when ArrayAdapter does this it errors out:

```
    text.setText(item.toString());
```

It's trying to call your object's `toString()` and failing. Either make sure you're not adding nulls or add Strings to your ArrayAdapter. Here's the line in question: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#394